# How to add a textField to a toolbar

Tags: ios4, sdk, iphone

I have a toolbar where I want to post a textField. I'm trying with the following code but it doesn't work:

```
 UIBarButtonItem *customItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(action:)];

 UITextField *customItem1 = [[UITextField alloc] init];

     NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: customItem, customItem1, nil]; 
[self setToolbarItems:items animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The toolbar items must all be UIBarButtonItems. In order to display something else, you embed a view into the item:

```
UIBarButtonItem *customItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:view];
//view is the embedded view, in your case a UITextField
```

Comment: looks fine but Im not sure how to convert UITextField to a view :S it doesn't crash now, it only displays the button now tho

Comment: Set text field frame and add this text field with initWithCustomView as a argument. Dont worry about type casting.